# How do I solve this relative velocity question consisting of 3 objects?

Tags: vectors

An aeroplane is observed by two persons travelling at  $60 \frac{km}{hr} $ in two vehicles moving in opposite directions on a straight road. To an observer in one vehicle the plane appears to cross the road track at right angles while to the observer in the other vehicle the angle appears to be $45°$. At what angle does the plane actually cross the road track and what is its speed relative to the ground.
My attempt :
Now for vehicle 1 $$ \vec{V_{p1}} =\vec{V_{p}}-\vec{V_{1}} $$ where  $ \vec{V_{p}}$ is velocity of plane.
Similarly for vehicle 2
$$ \vec{V_{p2}} =\vec{V_{p}}-\vec{V_{2}} $$
How should I proceed further? I am stuck at this step.

Answer (score 0):

The velocity difference between the cars is $120km/h$. That means that the observed plane velocity differs by $120km/h$ along the road, but they observe the velocity component perpendicular to the road to be the same.

One car thinks the plane moves perpendicular to the road, which means that the plane's velocity component along the road is $0km/h$. The other car thinks that the plane's velocity component along the road is $120km/h$, but he also thinks that it is equal to the component perpendicular to the road, because of $45^\circ$.

That means that the second car sees the plane moving at $120km/h$ perpendicular to the road, and $120km/h$ along the road. The plane's ground speed is therefore $120km/h$ perpendicular to the road and $60km/h$ along the road.

Comment: How do you know that the velocity difference between the cars is $  120 km/h$

Comment: @arutoregni Because they're both moving at $60km/h$ relative to ground, and away from each other. That means that the difference between their velocities is $60km/h + 60km/h = 120km/h$

Answer (score 0):

The left figure below depicts the actual velocity vectors of the vehicles. The right figure depicts the relative velocity vectors. Clearly, the angles between the relative velocity vectors correspond to the data given:

[image: ![enter image description here]
Then the real angle between the path of the plane and the road is
$$\color{green}{\alpha=\arctan\left(\frac{120}{60}\right)=\arctan(2)}.$$

Comment: The angle is given as $\alpha =arctan2 $

Comment: @arutoregni: I am confused. Is the definition of tangent not opposite side / adjacent side? In our case (green vector) the opposite side is $60$ and the adjacent side is $120$.

Comment: @arutoregni: I've got it. My green alpha is not the angle of the plane's path and the road. I will correct my answer immediately. THX:

Comment: @arutoregni: Answer is corrected.